# Group by and count on list lambda c#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I have 2 tables in the database **Department** and **SubDepartment**. Each department can or cannot have multiple sub departments. I am fetching the data from both the tables combined in the form of following class.

*This class have more properties as well from both the tables.*

```
public class Department
{
   public int DepartmentId { get; set; } 
   public string DepartmentName { get; set; } 
   public int SubDepartmentId { get; set; } 
   public string SubDepartmentName { get; set; } 
}
```

For example data can be Department as **Science** which will have multiple Sub Departments as **Physics**, **Chemistry**. Also Department can be **English** which will have one sub department as **English** only.

Now from the data in the form of List of Departments collection fetched from the DB I have to fetch those departments which have multiple sub departments.

Below is the code:

```
List<Department> departments = new List<Department>();
// Here fetching deptids which are having multi sub deptids
var multidepartmentIds = departments .GroupBy(x => x.DepartmentId)
           .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
           .Select(x => new { DepartmentId = x.Key }).ToList();

// Here getting the entire data/item for each dept and subdept
var finalDeptData = departments.Where(x => multidepartmentIds.Any(y => y.DepartmentId == x.DepartmentId)).ToList();
```

Is there a better way to implement this?

**I have thought of one more way as well where in a single lambda statement after Count we can have an anonymous type with all the class properties but the problem is that I have to return this collection to the caller method and then in that case I have to return the anonymous collection as type *object* which will require changes in the caller method as well.**

Any help??

Comment: Doesn´t the `.Where(x => x.Count() > 1)` already give you the departments? Why looping the results again?

Comment: Shouldn't a `Department` have a `List<SubDepartment>` instead of `SubDepartmentId` and `SubDepartmentName`?

Comment: I don't see how this code addresses the number of subdepartments.

Comment: @AndrewMorton From sub department table I am not using much of the columns of that table just the primary key and deptname thats why i thought of adding them as properties in the same class or the common class and not added as a list property. Most of the properties I will use for the data is of Department table.Sub dept data i am just using to implement this logic(to get the count of sub depts)

Comment: @csharpnewbie The way it is shown in the question, the department data is replicated for every subdepartment. That is wasteful and can lead to errors. A subdepartment can be a different class - it doesn't have to have all the members of the department class.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, IMO you are trying to get a list of all sub-departments which their department has multiple sub-department. In this case, you can do this:

```
List<Department> departments = new List<Department>();
// Here fetching deptids which are having multi sub deptids
var multidepartmentIds = departments
       .GroupBy(x => x.DepartmentId)
       .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
       .SelectMany(x => x)
       .ToList();
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the inner `ToList` in the `SelectMany`?

Comment: The `ToList()` in the `SelectMany` is completely redundant.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create an anonymous type to hold a single value. Since you are looking for matches in the collection of IDs, use a `HashSet` to hold them:

```
// Here fetching deptids which are having multi sub deptids
var multidepartmentIds = departments.GroupBy(d => d.DepartmentId)
                                    .Where(dg => dg.Count() > 1)
                                    .Select(dg => dg.Key)
                                    .ToHashSet();

// Here getting the entire data/item for each dept and subdept
var finalDeptData = departments.Where(d => multidepartmentIds.Contains(d.DepartmentId)).ToList();
```

However, since all you really want is all the `departments` where there are multiple occurrences, you can do that in one statement:

```
// find all departments with multiple sub deptids and return them
var finalDeptData2 = departments.GroupBy(d => d.DepartmentId)
                                .Where(dg => dg.Count() > 1)
                                .SelectMany(dg => dg)
                                .ToList();
```

I like to have an extension method for this:

```
public static class IEnumerableExt {
    public static IEnumerable<T> DuplicatesBy<T,TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T,TKey> keyFn, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer = null)
        => src.GroupBy(s => keyFn(s), comparer).Where(sg => sg.Count() > 1).SelectMany(sg => sg);
}
```

Which you can use like:

```
var findDeptData3 = departments.DuplicatesBy(d => d.DepartmentId).ToList();
```

Comment: Your first block of code is just confusing the situation. The `SelectMany` approach is the most simple way to do this.

Comment: @Enigmativity I think it helps explain in the general case when/why it is better to use `HashSet<int>` instead of `List<{anonymous type}>` for matching.